# Need for Intent.createChooser method when using implicit Intent

Tags: android

I don't understand why one needs to use Intent.createChooser when using implicit intent. According to Android docs "If multiple intent filters are compatible, the system displays a dialog so the user can pick which app to use". So if the android system pops up a chooser dialog why to use createChooser method?

Thank u in advance

Comment: Do task with Intent without using createChooser, and then with createChosser. Picture will be clear

Answer (score 2):

yes, android system will do this for you. But once you choose an item from the dialog, the system will keep it  in mind and it will **NOT** show the dialog next time if the user chooses a "default". this isn't always what you want. Suppose you have a share button, you certainly don't want your users to share with a same approach all the time. So it's the case where you'll need a `createChooser` call. This forces the system to show the choosing dialog each time.

you can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-text-content)